# Vertical Carousel in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a vertical carousel on bootstrap 5. I'm using [this code](https://codepen.io/iordachs/pen/zYxXyoW) for reference. I understand it was built on a different version of bootstrap but I can't seem to translate it to bootstrap 5. I have this so far. When ran, the website is blank. I'm also not sure if I've linked the CSS and JS properly in my html.

HTML

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/scripts.js')}}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='less/mystyles.less')}}">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="carousel slide vertical" id="carousel-vertical" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-bs-target="#carousel-vertical" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-bs-target="#carousel-vertical" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-bs-target="#carousel-vertical" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>



</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var delta = 0;
    var scrollThreshold = 5;
  
    // detect available wheel event
    wheelEvent = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : // Modern browsers support "wheel"
        document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" :         // Webkit and IE support at least "mousewheel"
        "DOMMouseScroll";                                            // let's assume that remaining browsers are older Firefox
  
    // Bind event handler
    $(window).on(wheelEvent, function (e) {
        // Do nothing if we weren't scrolling the carousel
        var carousel = $('.carousel.vertical:hover');
        if (carousel.length === 0)  return;
  
        // Get the scroll position of the current slide
        var currentSlide = $(e.target).closest('.item')
        var scrollPosition = currentSlide.scrollTop();
  
        // --- Scrolling up ---
        if (e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            // Do nothing if the current slide is not at the scroll top
            if(scrollPosition !== 0) return;
  
            delta--;
  
            if ( Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {
                delta = 0;
                carousel.carousel('prev');
            }
        }
  
        // --- Scrolling down ---
        else {
            // Do nothing if the current slide is not at the scroll bottom
            var contentHeight = currentSlide.find('> .content').outerHeight();
            if(contentHeight > currentSlide.outerHeight() && scrollPosition + currentSlide.outerHeight() !== contentHeight) return;
  
            delta++;
            if (delta >= scrollThreshold)
            {
                delta = 0;
                carousel.carousel('next');
            }
        }
  
        // Prevent page from scrolling
        return false;
    });
  })
```

CSS(less)

```
.carousel .item {
  padding-bottom: 720/1280 * 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  
  &:nth-child(1) { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720?text=Slide 1'); }
  &:nth-child(2) { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720?text=Slide 2'); }
  &:nth-child(3) { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720?text=Slide 3'); }
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
}
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
  }
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active {
  top: 0;
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators,
.carousel-indicators-vertical {
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**1) Getting the right setup for Bootstrap :**

- you have **2 ways** of using the framework -> **download** the files OR **link** the files
- **which one** should you use ? I like downloading the files better so I can go and see what's going on. It also allows me to **modify** the things I want from the source code and not do "**orders / counter-orders**" with my own CSS / JS files.
- **where** to get those **links** -> in Bootstrap "Getting Started" section (homepage - link [here](https://getbootstrap.com/))
- **where** to **download** the files ? -> in Bootstrap download section ([here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/))
- **where** should you place the links / scripts ? -> Links are in the `head` section of HTML but I really suggest putting the script right before the end of the `body`. Why ? So your HTML structure/elements are loaded, and **THEN** only you can put eventlisteners and modifiers on those loaded elements.

---

**2) How to make the carousel vertical ?**

- how does it currently **work** ? The carousel works in **horizontal** mode using Bootstrap Framework. If you go into their CSS files, you will understand how it works. It mainly uses a `float: left`, `display:none` and `transform: translateX(...)` properties to make it work horizontally.
- **what** must you do to make it **vertical** ? Well, you need to get the `float:left` **off** the code and you need to change the `transform-:translateX(...)` to a `transform-:translateY(...)`
- transitions, **awful** ? I know, it doesn't look great. One thing you can do, first, to make it a little less "jumpy", is set a **fixed** `height` to the `carousel-inner` class.
- If you want the buttons (next / previous) to be vertical, you will need to work on their positionning (currently, their classes are in `left: 0` / `right: 0` .
  The classes are : `.carousel-control-prev /.carousel-control-next`

---

**3) Illustrated idea:**

What **vertical CSS modifications** look like :

[image: First CSS elements]

[image: Second CSS elements]

**More info** on the *"Getting the right setup for Bootstrap"* :

The **link files** of Bootstrap :

[image: link files]

The **download section** of Bootstrap :

[image: download link files]

The **.zip files for CSS**, example :
Don't forget to "link" the download files into your html.
Example for CSS : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.css">`

[image: what files to use]

Comment: Good solution! However, the automatic sliding feature of the carousel does not work after implementing this. Any idea to make that work too?